# Why is "defau4t" legal in a switch statement?

Tags: c++, c, switch-statement, default

I came up with this program in some other site and thought of trying it, here's the program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a=10;
    switch(a)
    {
         case '1': printf("one");
                   break;
         case '2': printf("two");
                   break;
         defau4t:  printf("none");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Suprisingly enough, this compiles without errors or warnings. How is this possible? Isn't there an error on keyword "default"?
Could anyone explain this behaviour?

Comment: Compiler interprets it as `goto` label.

Comment: `gcc` explains it in a warning: `14:10: warning: label 'defau4t' defined but not used`

Comment: No warnings in case of gcc.. Am I using a different version from yours?

Comment: @darknight: Are you perhaps using GCC without `-Wall -Wextra` at the very least? ;-)

Comment: Nope, my command is just "gcc test.c"

Comment: @darknight: Well then, so you have learned two things in one question. ;-)

Comment: You should always call gcc as `gcc -std=c99 -pedantic-errors -Wall -Wextra` (where c99 may be replaced with c11 or c90). Just calling it as `gcc test.c` will not only miss out on a lot of dangerous practice, it will also expect you to pass a program written in some fantasy, non-standard GNU language, rather than the ISO standard C language.

Comment: Personally, I'd add `-Werror` to that, but that's taking it OT too far.

Comment: `defau1t` (with a `1` instead of `l`) would be even more vicious.

Comment: To call `gcc` with specific flags, you can simple use `make program` where `program.c` is the source code and put `CFLAGS = -std=c99 -Wall -Werror` (or whatever you need) in a `Makefile`. The rest is done by the automatic logic of GNU `make` at the least.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The token is not considered to be a keyword at all. This is a `goto` jump mark named "defau4t" pointing at otherwise dead code (after the `break;` of `case '2':`)...

Try this for laughs (and an endless loop):

```
switch(a)
{
     case '1': printf("one");
               break;
     case '2': printf("two");
               break;
     defau4t: printf("none");
     default: goto defau4t;
}
```

Comment: Ok, then what happens when I actually use default?

Comment: In your case this switch will just be ommited.

Comment: Good compilers will warn about goto-labels which are never used... at least if you ask them nicely: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`

Comment: @DevSolar In OP's case it becomes dead code so compiler would optimize it right?

Comment: @Mr.32: Optimizations are a tricky subject, bound to change with compiler version and compiler flags used. The compiler *could* optimize the dead code in the OP's source away, warn about it, or do neither.

Comment: So, "default: goto case '1'" means getting default: line and go to case '1' line? really?

Comment: @JaeHyukLee: No. `goto` and `case` / `default` labels are not interchangeable (AFAIK), they just share a common syntax (the trailing colon). In my code, `case '1':`, `case '2':` and `default:` are part of the `switch` construct. `defau4t:` is a jump label, which just happens to be *in* the `switch` construct. You cannot `goto case '1':` any more than any value of `a` could make the jump to `defau4t:`.

Answer (score 4):

One flaw with the `switch` statement is that you can wildly jump in and out of them using `goto`. At any point inside the `switch` (or outside it for that matter), you can place a *label*, that you can jump to with `goto`. Of course, that is very bad practice as it leads to spaghetti code.

So `defau4t:` is merely a label, and labels can be placed pretty much anywhere inside function bodies.

Comment: The problem isn't so much a deficiency with `switch` as the very existence of `goto`, which I haven't ever used in over 15 years in the profession except for bad examples. ;-)

Comment: @DevSolar Two good uses of goto: jumping out of nested loops (sure you can use a "shouldExit" bool but it's ugly and less efficient) - and error handling within a function.

Comment: @DevSolar The problem is that `case` and `default` look like labels and behave like labels. Also, the switch comes with some built-in "spaghetti features" like the dangerous fall-through mechanism if you forget a `break`, as illustrated in your own example. When you mix several spaghetti features together, you get terrible code.

Comment: @JamesMcLaughlin Those are not "good" uses, those are tolerable uses. The consensus of the 50 year old goto debate is pretty much that programmers do recognize that there are valid reasons to use goto, but that we shouldn't use it anyway, since it is a 100% superfluous feature. The whole goto debate in itself is reason enough to avoid it... :)

Comment: @Lundin: Well, the big 666 someone painted on it is a good reason to avoid it, yes. But even Djikstra never argued for a perma-ban, just for giving structured programming a chance, where it is the most concise (and efficient enough) alternative. Good code uses `goto` where it is the best tool, and nowhere else.

Comment: @Deduplicator Every code using `goto` can be refactored to a form without `goto` (simplest way: using (inline) functions, decomposing the code before, and after the `goto`). `goto` gives no gain, so being less readable, it can never be "the best tool" for anything. I assume you may have some simple example, or counter argument - if yes, I will gladly consider it, but won't reply for the sake of not starting a comment war ;)

Comment: Every code using `for` can be refactored to use `while` and every code using `switch` can be refactored to use a series of `if` and `else`. Fighting against each single use of `goto` is a religious nonsense. Your energy can be better spend on fighting against obviously bad code or writing good one.

Comment: I constantly use `goto` to break out of multiple loops.

Comment: @BartoszKP Sorry, but following a single-entry, single-exit model in C with a `goto` label at the end to clean up multiple resources is very often far more readable than duplicating the cleanup code for every exit point, for having many levels of nested `if` blocks, or for decomposing it into multiple one-time-use functions and passing around many variables. (That doesn't apply to C++, however, where one could use RAII instead.)

Comment: The only valid places where goto is acceptable are as mentioned: by breaking out of nested loops or for error handling ("on error goto"). In both these cases, goto can be replaced by a return from the function. I find this much more readable than a goto + a label. So even in the few cases where the use goto is valid, there are better alternatives: making goto a 100% superfluous language feature.

Comment: @Lundin You can just return in C++ where you can leverage destructors; not so in C.

Comment: @jamesdlin You can do it in C too, just put the memory allocation in the base function, which in turn calls the actual algorithm function. That way you also keep the algorithm pure from unrelated tasks, letting it focus on the actual thing it is supposed to do, rather than memory handling.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from that typo of default.

i think you need to also update

```
     case '1': printf("one");
               break;
     case '2': printf("two");
               break;
```

to

```
     case 1: printf("one");
               break;
     case 2: printf("two");
               break;
```

Comment: That depends on whether `'1'` and `'2'` were typos, or if he actually *wants* to check against the implementation-defined encoding value of the characters "1" and "2", one of which might actually equate to `(int)10` on his platform of choice. ;-) (+1 of course, you're absolutely right.)

Comment: No.. That was not an issue, either way I meant it to go to default case

Comment: This is not really an answer to the question, just a comment on the code.